# R - Is there a way to join two dataframes by actually merging same-named columns?

Tags: r, join, merge

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is generally not possible, that a -1 and 1 are at the same spot. Therefore, this is not a problem that should bother. Also, both dataframes have the same number of columns and observations. The final product should not have .x or .y files, like Var1.x and Var.y. My attempts to solve this with the join function all failed, because it always only merges those two dataframes instead of joining columns together. I might have to add that the number of columns and observations is very high. Therefore, taking the column names into account in the code does not solve my problem.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Instead of screenshots you might want to supply some data that's directly copy and paste-able.

Comment: Paste data into the question using `dput(your_dataframe)`. [MRE] and [ask] may be helpful

Comment: Sorry everyone. I tried to insert tables and it worked in preview. However, when posting the question it was displayed totally chaotically and unformated. I paniced and just made screenshots. Next time I will also give some example code when my data is that big, however another user did it right down below this time.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all elegant, but it may work fine

```
A[is.na(A)]<- 0
B[is.na(B)]<- 0

C = A[,-1] + B[,-1]

C[] <- sign(C)

C[C==0] <- NA

C = data.frame(ID = A[,1], C)
```

Comment: Upvote but instead of two test for the sign of `C` why not `C[] <- sign(C)`?

Comment: Interesting and simple, I didn't know of this before.

Comment: Maybe exclude the column `ID` during this operations.

Comment: Oh yes, I added your suggestions in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

These two simple dataframes can be used as an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  var1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4, NA),
  var2 = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  var1 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5),
  var2 = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5)
)
```

We can now join them using `inner_join` and then pivot them to a longer format.

```r
(df_joined_long <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = "id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c("var", ".value")))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id var       x     y
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 var1      1    NA
#>  2     1 var2      1    NA
#>  3     2 var1      2    NA
#>  4     2 var2      2    NA
#>  5     3 var1     NA     3
#>  6     3 var2     NA     3
#>  7     4 var1      4    NA
#>  8     4 var2     NA     4
#>  9     5 var1     NA     5
#> 10     5 var2     NA     5
```

In this form we now only have to deal with two columns. We want to replace missing values from `x` with non-missing values from `y` and vice-versa. This can be dones using `coalesece`. After doing that, we simply pivot back to the wide format.

```r
df_joined_long %>% 
  mutate(val = coalesce(x, y), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = val)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id  var1  var2
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3
#> 4     4     4     4
#> 5     5     5     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that the variables are not that easy to handle with. In reality they are not called Var1, Var2...Var1000 and have random names without pattern.

Comment: But they still have similar names across the two dataframes right?

Comment: They have the same names in df1 and df2, yes. But they vary within those dataframes. The names are 3535, 303003, 20405... without any pattern.

Comment: The suggested code should still work in that case. I'm not relying on any patterns in the column names in my suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.frame`'s could be subsetted with the positions where the `NA`'s are located e.g. in *A* and overwrite with that what is in *B* at this positions.

```
i <- is.na(A)
A[i] <- B[i]
#C <- `[<-`(A, i, value=B[i]) #In case A should not be changed

A
#  id var1 var2
#1  1    1   -1
#2  2   -1    1
#3  3    1   NA
#4  4   NA   -1
#5  5   -1    1
```

Data:

```
A <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  var1 = c(1, -1, NA, NA, NA),
  var2 = c(-1, 1, NA, NA, NA)
)

B <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  var1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, -1),
  var2 = c(NA, NA, NA, -1, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this data:

```
df.A <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                   Var1 = NA,
                   Var2 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1),
                   Var3 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1))

df.B <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                   Var1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                   Var2 = c(-1, NA, 1, NA, NA),
                   Var3 = NA)
```

First we inner_join both columns like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df.A %>%
  inner_join(df.B, by="ID")
```

Then we can start a for loop based on column names (does not require string matches so any column name works as long as they match in A and B):

```
for (i in 2:ncol(df.B)) {
  col <- names(df.B[i])
  df <- df %>%
    mutate("{col}" := coalesce(!!as.name(paste0(col, ".x")), !!as.name(paste0(col, ".y"))))
}
```

Lastly we remove the columns we don't need:

```
df %>% select(!contains(c(".x", ".y")))
```